# Choosing between software load balancer and hardware load balancer

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, haproxy, f5

I wonder if there are any situations where one would prefer software load balancer over hardware load balancer or vice-versa. I've played around with f5, A10, Nginx, and HAproxy briefly, and the only marginal difference I was able to notice was the price, apart from slightly better API documentation etc. 
So my question is:
**Are there any particular use cases where one would prefer Software load balancers over hardware load balancers or vice-versa?**

Feel free to quote your experience, where you preferred one over the other and, rationale you used to make that decision.

PS: I have read [5 reasons to prefer S/W load balancers over H/W load balancers](https://www.nginx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/NGINX_Ebook_5Reasons_02_0728b.pdf) and didn't find explanations there very propelling.

EDIT: Regarding my use case, I'll be needing lot of load balancers to secure/load-balance tons of apps. Therefore the design decision should be such, as to cope up with exponentially increasing number of apps behind it (Should be easily scalable). I'm not looking for 10 or 50 app load balancer but at tons of thousands of apps behind load balancer**s** solution. Also it would be great if you can specifically point out at features which outweigh in H/W over S/W or vice-versa. For example with H/W load balancer FPGA services one can do SSL offloading and can acheive an order of X performance gain given that one has more than Y number of apps behind it etc.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't going to be a single answer to this question as it will always depend on your application requirements and your compliance obligations.  Companies like F5, A10, Citrix offer services that expand well past basic load balancing and offer features lb just cannot touch.

If you're JUST looking for lb services and maybe some SSL bridging or offloading here are some benefits:

1. Hardware: Offer hardware accelerated SSL offloading and bulk encryption due to the use of FPGA services.  This is also dependent on what cipher suites you plan to use.  With hardware you're usually placing them in front of 100's of applications or you're using it because they may be certified firewalls and you need additional requirements for compliancy.
2. Software:  If you just need basic LB, HAProxy/Nginx are an easy choice for basic lb services and even some SSL services.  Support is mixed if you're not paying for it, having to rely only on community examples.

However, if you have mixed environments and maybe already have 1 vendor in play, that can help decide.  All of the hardware vendors offer virtual appliances and have automation tools to help with elastic environments so really it ends up being "Will you only ever need LB services or will you end up having to tack on more later"?

The F5/A10/Citrix ADC's in cloud still offer more features in a single platform than having to spin up segregated services (think firewall/load balancing/Web firewall/global load balancing/fraud prevention/analytics/access management).

**Updated 6/21/2017:**

Hardware: People are buying hardware solutions not to proxy 1 or 2 applications but 100 or 200, or even 1000 or 2000 applications in their data centers (on site or collocated).  For these cases it's about performance and services beyond lb.  It includes security needs and app protection that are not baked into HAproxy and Nginx.

ADC Vendors Software Solutions:  You have 3 options because F5/A10/Citrix also sell virtual appliances allowing you to run the same software in Azure/AWS/Google or in VMWare.... you get the idea.  This becomes unique because you can have hardware in your co-location and virtual appliances in your cloud solution and its the same vendor and the bonus for your admins, the same support escalation point.

HAproxy/Nginx Softare:  This goes back to the original statement, if you're talking LB solution only and price is a concern, this is your way to go.  The feature sets are more limited than the ADC/Security solutions above, but they do LB justfine.  It can become a bit cumbersome managing 100's of apps so you'll have to rely on your dev team a bit more to make sure they're isolating environments OR are REALLY good at automation.

The decision comes down to will you only need load balancers?  If yes, then HAproxy/Nginx.  If you need more features to load balance AND protect your app, then ADC software solutions are the way to go.

If you need reliable performance and cannot justify dedicating one vm per host to achieve it, then hardware ADC's are the way to go.

For transparency, I work on the DevCentral team at F5 so I would love to say go hardware, but if you don't need it don't do it. But its going to come down to your application requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Are you suggesting that software load balancers are only used in small scale environments or mostly when you are just starting out with your app. And once you start getting high amount of traffic one should move to H/W load balancers?

Comment: I've edited my question to be more precise about my use case, please do have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The follow up question is what is your application and requirements for a load-balancer?

Generally hardware LB's have a fixed performance and hardware acceleration to assist with SSL offload.  Software or virtual performance can fluctuate with an increased load and then you can run into bugs with performance, but it's easier to deploy and scale.

Other questions to look into is, will you need to modify or redirect traffic based on content?  For example, rewriting or filtering traffic?  If yes, then you may need a full proxy LB.

Comment: Thanks for your anwer, I've edited my question to be more precise about my use case, please do have a look.